# Calculate vector orientation in QGIS manually using raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am trying to make an ocean current map, where I have .nc file contains velocity u0 and v0.

Calculating magnitude, and orientation using a vector field calculator plugin is very easy. But recently my plugin is not working so I tried to calculate magnitude and orientation using raster calculator,
where, magnitude = `sqrt(u0^2 + v0^2)`
and orientation = `acos(u0*v0/(abs(u0)*(abs(v0)))`
after doing that my maps looks like this.

[image]

but it should look like this while using vector field calc. [image]

All the process are same except for the calculation, I think the formula of orientation is wrong.

What should I change?

Comment: The formula you seem to be applying for orientation is meant for vectors (the * is not a multiplication but a dot product) . My understanding is that your u0/v0 are the components of the current. In that case, you'll get the orientation based on atan(v0/u0) when u0 is positive. Add Pi radians when u0 is negative: `atan(v0/u0)+3.14159*(u0<0)`. This gives you 0 for east going current, 90 for north going currents. Then rotate / convert to degrees according to your needs

Comment: Thank you sir, but sir the ranges of my u0 value is from -x to +x, it is a .nc file. so  do i use the same equation atan(v0/u0)+3.14159*(u0<0).

Comment: By my understanding, it should work, if u0 and v0 are orthogonal components of the current speed.